# Maximization of a statistical property of a subset of random numbers

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, optimization

I have encountered a maximization problem which could be formulated as a discrete mathematics problem arising from statistics, but I don't know where to start or which techniques could be applied to it.

Assume you have $N$ positive numbers $\rho_i$, $i=1,...,N$. What is the index subset $I\subseteq \{1,\dots,N\}$ that maximizes the quantity
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N_I}}\sum_{j\in I}\rho_j=\sqrt{N_I} \bar\rho_I
$$
where $N_I$ is the number of elements in $I$ and $\bar{\rho_I}$ is the mean value of the subset $\{\rho_i: i\in I\}$.

I have run a numerical test and the answer does not seem obvious. On the other hand for large $N$ the number of subsets is $2^N$, which is prohibitively large for moderate $N$ to check one by one (in my case $N=121$). Could somebody point to a discrete optimization algorithm that could be used to find the maximum (assuming there is no easy "analytical solution")? Many thanks!

Comment: OK, I think I have found a relatively easy way, but I don't know if it is correct: from all the subsets with the same $N_I$  the one that maximizes the mean value is the subset where we neglect the $N-N_I$ smallest numbers of the set $\rho_1,\rho_2,\dots,\rho_N$. Hence one has only to check $N$ subsets instead of $2^N$ to find the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think it suffices to consider an $N$-element subset of all $2^N$ possible subsets: If you order $\rho_i$ descendingly, the index set $I$ maximizing your quantity will contain exactly the first $N_I$ elements of the ordering.

If $\pi{:}\ [N]\to[N]$ is the ordering operator and $\phi_i=\rho_{\pi(i)}$, you will get $\phi_1\ge\phi_2\ge\dots$. Then, for a given $N_I$,

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{N_I}} \sum_{j\in I} \phi_j$$

is maximized for $I=\{1,2,\dots,N_I\}$. It remains to determine $N_I$, but in this regard you might find help in the theory of [order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Comment: I see we had the exact same thought almost at the same time! Thank you very much nevertheless, this confirms that my thought was not wrong!

Comment: Yes, I just saw it too, nice coincidence! Do you also need to find $N_I$?

Comment: Yes, that is the ultimate goal, but for my computational resources and size of the problem it should not be such a big problem to just blindly parse through all $N$ subsets and find the optimum. Thanks again for your time and effort!